# Permission Error in Setting up Ground Truth Labeling in AWS S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I am currently trying to create a labeling job for a csv dataset stored under
my bucketname. In order to have access for the labeling job, I needed to update the
bucket policy for my bucketname.

I followed the tutorial: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/sms-security-permission-console-access.html,
however, I am getting the error "Unsupported Action in Policy" for `groundtruthlabeling:*`, despite it being shown on the sidebar. I tried selecting each individual checkbox for the access levels, but each one had the same error.

What should be done to resolve this?

[image]